# How to check the latest version of the app with NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I want to check if user is using the latest version of the app. If so, i should color the background of some cells.

This is the code i'm using:

appDelegate.m

```
NSString *lastVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastVer"];
```

method where i want to check:

```
NSString *lastVersion = (NSString *) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastVer"];
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
lastVersion = @"1.3.4";
if(![lastVersion isEqualToString:version]){
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; ; 
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

  } 
  else { 
       cell.imageView.image = nil;
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }
}
```

Am i doing it right? Is my code checking for the latest version or? How can i simulate this behavior in the simulator \ on device?

What i want to do is check if the user is using the latest version of the app, in order to call in another NSUserDefaults key to show the cells of my tableView with a different background color.

**EDIT**

Code i'm using to change the cells background if the user is using the latest version of my app and if the user has used the app less than three times:

```
    NSString *cellValue = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSNumber *runNumber = (NSNumber *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"runNum"]; 
    NSString *lastVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastVer"];
    NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    if (!runNumber) { 
                runNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]; 
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:runNumber forKey:@"runNum"]; 
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 
            } 

    if([lastVersion isEqualToString:version]){ //check if the user is using the latest version
       if ([runNumber intValue] < 4) { //check if user has used the app less than 3 times 
           if ([cellValue isEqual: "someText"] ){ 
               cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; ; 
               cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
              } 
            else { 
            cell.imageView.image = nil;
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            } 
        }   
        else {
           cell.imageView.image = nil;
           cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
        }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this code will not set anything..

```
NSString *lastVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastVer"];
lastVersion = @"1.3.4";
```

you need a setter:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"1.3.4" forKey:@"lastVer"];//in memory
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];//to disk
```

and a getter:

```
NSString *lastVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastVer"];
```

edit:

remember that lastVersion is a pointer and you just set it to point somewhere else, that doesn't set it in stdUserDefaults and it doesn't synchronize it to disk.

Comment: And from it i will be able to compare the versions, right? I am getting an error using your code, though : `Semantic Issue: Initializing 'NSString *' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'` . As you can see above, i correct my code and i get that working by assigning to lastVersion the last version number.

Comment: sure. I don't know enough about what you are doing, but you can sure compare strings that contain numbers.

Comment: I am sure you are using a hybrid of your code and mine, i fixed mine to be more clear.

Comment: Could i use removeObjectForKey to reset a key everytime the user updates the app?

Answer (score 1):

Surely if you want to check if the user is using the latest version of the app you would need to check with an external resource.

e.g.

1. Simple HTTP request to your own server, which returns your latest app version.
2. Then compare this against your current version `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];`
3. Store the result of this test in `NSUserDefaults`